# Remove last characters after last space in a string

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm having string values like mentioned below.

**String Values:**

> George, Matt J
>
> Rambla, Tony G.

**Expected Output:**

> George, Matt
>
> Rambla, Tony

I would need to trim the letters like mentioned above. Can anyone help me with this?

I achieved the same in SQL Server by below query

```sql
declare @String as varchar(20) = 'Rambla, Tony G.'

select left(@string,len(@string)+1-charindex(' ',reverse(@string)))
```

How can I achieve this in MS Access?

I have tried these and doesn't help

**1st Method**

```sql
Left([ColumnName], Len([ColumnName]) -1)
```

**2nd Method**

```sql
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, INSTRREV(ColumnName, " "))
```

Comment: Waht do you mean by "in Access"? In Access VBA or Access SQL?

Comment: I would need in Access SQL.

Comment: `Left([ColumnName], InStrRev([ColumnName], " ") - 1)` works for me. Please explain why it "doesn't help"! Is your query a "real" Access query or a Pass-Through-query?

Comment: It's perfectly working, but I also do have string values like `Leo, Marcus` and it doesn't display and returns value like this `#Func!`. And for these type of string values I need to get the same string. Mine is an Access query.

Comment: It would seem that if you're having that problem in Access that you would also be having the problem in SQL Server, the problem being that it would not return the correct results for those exceptions.  Does that query also give you a problem in SQL Server with `Leo, Marcus`?

Comment: The query I use above for SQL and it works perfectly for Leo, Marcus.

Comment: Not for me. It deletes " Marcus". See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8ef5/1/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments it has become clear that the problem that you face, is to detect whether and how many characters have to be removed at the end. Since you are removing characters without testing if there is actually an abbreviated middle name there, neither your SQL-Server nor your Access-SQL solutions will work! Worse, if the Column is null or does not contain any space characters, then you might even get an exception.

I suggest to create a VBA Function and to call this one from your Access query, since the logic gets a bit complicated.

```vb
Public Function RemoveMiddleName(ByVal name As Variant) As Variant
    RemoveMiddleName = name
    If Not IsNull(name) Then
        Dim s As String, pos As Long, l As Long
        s = CStr(name)
        pos = InStrRev(s, " ")
        l = Len(s)
        If pos > 1 And l - pos <= 2 Then '1 or 2 characters at the end
            If l - pos = 1 Or (l - pos = 2 And Right$(s, 1) = ".") Then
                RemoveMiddleName = Left(s, pos - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Place this code in a VBA Module (not in a Form or Report).

And then call it like this:

```sql
SELECT RemoveMiddleName([ColumnName]) As FirstLast FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Trim(Left([columnname] & "  ",InStr(1+InStr([columnname] & "  "," "),[columnname] & "  "," ")))
```

Note the double space after each of the & - this ensures there are always at least 2 spaces in the search field.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to remove everything after last space character in a string

```
DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(100)='First Second Third'

select LEFT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@string)))
```

This will give you:

```
First Second
```